# Prove there exist points $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $G(x_0,y_0)=\max_{x,y \in I}G(x,y).$

Tags: real-analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* by Athur Mattuck:

> (a) Assume $f(x)$ integrable on $I$ and $a,x \in I$. Prove $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is continuous on $I$.
>
> (b) Suppose $I$ is compact and $f(x)$ is integrable on $I$. Define $$G(x,y)= \int _{x}^{y} f(t)dt.$$
>   Prove there exist points $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $G(x_0,y_0)=\max_{x,y \in I}G(x,y).$
>
> (Don't try to use guessed-at theorems about functions of two variables.)

(a) can be proved easily. I have not learned functions of two variables.

I guessed the function $M(x)=\max_{x,y \in I}G(x,y)$ is continuous on $I$. If so, (b) can be proved. But I don't know how to prove $M(x)$.

Comment: Can you express G as a sum of two function of one variable ?

Comment: What does (b) mean?  If the function $G$ achieves a maximum value, then there must be a point at which $G$ attains this maximum value.  Did you perhaps want to use supremum instead of maximum?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Sorry for my ignorance. don't know how.

Comment: @Hongyan look up the domain splitting property of integrals

Comment: @Batominovski $G$ is a function of two variables. But knowledge of functions of two variables is forbidden here.

Comment: @Hongyan  I'm not sure what you are talking about.  The definition of maximum is the supremum that **can be achieved**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the suggestion of @Quantaliinuxite is to write:

$$G(x,y)=F(y)-F(x),$$

where the point $a$ had been selected as the minimum of the set $I$. This is possible because $I$ is compact.

Then you can use that

$$\max\limits_{x,y\in I}{G(x,y)}=\max\limits_{y\in I}{F(y)}-\min\limits_{x\in I}{F(x)},$$

and applying the Weierstrass theorem for the function $F$ in the compact $I$, it is obtained

$$\max\limits_{x,y\in I}{G(x,y)}=F(y_0)-F(x_0)=G(x_0,y_0).$$

Comment: That is what I had in mind!

Comment: Nice!..............